# gevent-socketio emit or broadcast from python method

Tags: python, django, gevent, gevent-socketio

I use gevent-socketio library, and need to send message on `post_save`

```
...
def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
    // broadcast message with data(obj) to channel
```

How can i do this?

EDIT:

there is this example:

```
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace
from socketio.mixins import BroadcastMixin
from socketio.sdjango import namespace


@namespace('/document')
class DocumentNamespace(BaseNamespace, BroadcastMixin):

    def recv_connect(self):
        print "CONNECTED"

    def on_join(self, msg):
        self.broadcast_event('poruka', msg)

        print 'JOIN'
        return True

    def broadcast_msg(self, channel, msg):
        self.broadcast_event(channel, msg)
```

this example listen when client connect or send message to server, 
but i need to broadcast on my method `post_save` to client..

Comment: Its not clear what your question is. What are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: I added a example on question..